# DML Exception handling

Tags: master-detail, dmlexception

In a master-detail relationship, if there is an update of the detail, presence of roll-up summaries causes master record's updation. If the update on master fails owing to any validation rule, is there a way to track down master record's id using the standard methods for DMLException?

Comment: actually, the RSF on master may not execute depending on the CRUD action on the detail. For example a SUM of COUNT of details will not fire the RSF on master if the detail is being updated, as, by definition, the count hasn't changed

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm

The getDmlId method that is described toward the end of the page can be used in your "Catch' block to find the id of the record that failed to update (the master record, in this case).

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please mark my response as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Matt - BTW, SFSE etiquette is not to prompt so soon for your answer being the solution;   In this way, the community is unlike the SFDC Developer's Forum

Comment: Ah ok, thank you.